# No rule to make target /usr/lib/someLib.so

Tags: cmake

The build use to work in buntu 11.04, now in 12.04 it does not.

There is a conflict with the location of `someLib.so`.  That is, it is looking in the wrong location.  `/usr/lib/here/someLib.so` is the correct location.

When I run the 'c' configuration cmd in ccmake, it noticed the conflict,.. once.  Now ccmake no longer complains, but the err is still there.  `runtime library [someLib.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in: /usr/lib/here`

The lines in CMakeLists.txt that cause the build err are:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(test main.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test moreStuff evenMoreStuff)
```

I see the problem in the `build.make` file.  Which is generated by ccmake.  I can't figure out where ccmake is getting the idea that `someLib.so` is at `/usr/lib/`, rather than @ `/usr/lib/here/`.  I figure it would be a `SET()` statement somewhere.  I'm not finding it.

1) What is the configuration file (ccmake 'c' cmd) called?  Where would it be (same dir?)?
I figure if I del it, I'll be able to see the err again.  (Changing CMakeFile.txt doesn't seem to do it.)
2) How can I find out where the location of `someLib.so` is being set?  (What am I looking for?)

I hate CCMAKE.      Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this is an issue with one of find_library calls. If I remember correctly this was occurring when your environment was pointing to two different locations that both contained a library file with the same name.

You can prevent this from happening by either changing your environment so that it doesn't point to both locations or use one of NO_*_PATH with find_library call to prevent cmake from finding both locations (e.g. you could define your own path for this find_library and use NO_DEFAULT_PATH to prevent cmake from using environment paths - see documentation: [http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:find_library](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3afind_library))

find_library(someLib_location NAMES someLib PATHS /usr/lib/here/ NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

Regarding 1) I think they are called CMakeCache files but the safest way to go is simply delete the entire build structure (not a problem if you are building out of source)

Regarding 2) I would search throug CMakeList.txt files by library name (without .so suffix and lib prefix as those are probbably added by CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES and CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES variables)

Comment: The someLib.so only exist in one place. There is something telling CMAKE that it wrongly exists in /usr/lib.  Where does CMAKE get it's environment data?  Is there some CMAKE command that does it?  There is nothing in env that is setting it.  Are there other system environment files/settings that I need to check?  Thanks

Comment: Hm I never had that type of an issue... You should try to asking this question on CMake mailing list http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/mailing.html

Comment: The issue was one projects' CMAKE files referencing another projects' CMAKE files. So one project inherited another projects' settings.  So in a sad kind of way, this projects settings are tied to another, or another, or another,....

Comment: If both projects are your own I'd sudgest that you write a top cmake list (myCommonLibs.cmake) in which you search for all the libraries that you need for the entire project and in other CMakeList.txt files you only reference the set variables. I did this in our projects (wrote one common file for all the projects to include once - checks with if statements at the top of each cmake list) and marked them as advanced so they didn't show up in ccmake gui. It's a lot easier to track your library settings if they are set on one location.

Answer (score 1):

First I suggest to check if the package is already installed using the following command:

```
dpkg -L SomeLib
```

If it was not installed, install it using apt-get or any other method and try again. If it's installed but located under wrong location, use the link command to create the correct location like this:

```
sudo ln -s locationOfLibFromAboveCommand locationItShouldBe
```

I hope it helps.